# Кодирование в байтовый формат

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы, байты

Мне необходимо открыть файл с текстом так, чтобы я продолжил работать с байтами

Если необходимо работать со строками в байтовом формате, то обычно делают так - `b'anystring'`

Но как быть с файлом? Если мы напишем так: `as='anystring'` , и нам дальше надо работать именно с `as`, предварить этот `as`  буквой `b` -`bas` мы не можем -**чушь**.

```
f=open('file.txt','+')
```

Как быть дальше?

Манипуляции с `bytes() , bytearray()` ничем успешным не закончились

Comment: У `open()` есть параметры, а у *file object* — методы. Дальше документация вам в помощь!

Comment: `f=open('file.txt', 'rb')`. Если напишете `as=b'anystring'`, дальше можно использовать `as` без каких либо префиксов. Префикс нужен только литералам.

Comment: @extrn , не выходит, хотя бы глянь на вывод в `print()`

Comment: Приведите текст, который иллюстрирует, что у вас не работает с вариантом от extrn. Вроде бы он всё правильно написал.

Comment: что именно не выходит? какой именно вывод? https://repl.it/@exrnhe/bytes

Comment: `open('file.txt', 'rb')` отлично работает. Если нет — приведите пример, в котором это не работает, и print этот свой напишите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Не надо рассказывать сказки читайте документацию*

```
In [3]: string = 'anystring'

In [4]: byte = bytes(string, "utf-8")

In [5]: byte
Out[5]: b'anystring'
```

*Вообще для работы с байтами есть встроенные функции*

```
encode()

decode()
```

**Пример**

```
In [2]: string = "строка"

In [3]: _bytes = string.encode("utf-8")

In [4]: _bytes
Out[4]: b'\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'

In [5]: string = _bytes.decode("utf-8")

In [6]: string
Out[6]: 'строка'
```

Comment: И "as" это ключевое слово. as='anystring' эта строчка вызовет ошибку.

Comment: `import time
a=open('eric.txt','rb')
print(a.read())
time.sleep(5)`

Comment: Про `as` верно, да, я в курсе, я просто привел пример вот так вот неудачно